# Are there vines in nature that are naturally capable of being used as a whip (weapon), rope or as strings?

Tags: ropes, knots, trees, tree-climbing, jungle

Natural meaning, no human alteration to them besides chopping them off from a tree or any type of plant.

Ways I'm wondering if natural vines can be used.

- As a weapon, such as such as the bullwhip.
- As a rope for tying up objects.
- As a "jump rope" that can consistently hit the ground for a while without being damaged.

Traditional braided (human altered) vines won't solve the question, because I'm purely interested in whether there are any species of vines capable of being used for the above applications without editing their natural design.

I'm not knowledgable whatsoever about the vines of trees or any other plants. I've tried finding information online but I haven't personally had success finding information pertaining to the strength or flexibility of different vines.

Some characteristics I'm wondering if any species of vines have.

- How thick can a plants vine be.
- Are there only large vines with bark around them, or are there large vines (green) that are like a flowers "branches".

Comment: See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yza3eXZPjuM)  From a blog entitled "bushcraft".  Author used a wild vine as cordage in first stages of making a shelter.  This isn't enough for an Answer, but I do  not have time to write an answer.  Anyone:  feel free to use this comment in your own answer.

Comment: When your question is closed, especially for needing more details, please edit that question rather than asking a new question.

Comment: I have edited your original question for you. Just the header might still need editing.